# How to pause UIView Animations

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

in iOS5.0 using blocks, say if we have an UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animation, and need to put in a delay before the reverse animation starts.. how can we do this?

Thanks for your help on this

Comment: Haven't really used this myself but have you tried the completion block in the animate message? I'd be interested in your result.

Comment: One more idea (which is probably the easiest): Have you just tried adding a delay at the end of your initial animation? I'd expect that the delay you define doubles, however it could also be ignored by the reverse animation and you only get the delay once.

Comment: how does one add a delay in block animations?

Answer (score 2):

```
The best way to pause and resume animation :

add QuartzCore framework 


then use the following apple's code 

-(void) pause
{

CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [m_pCustomImageBtnObj.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];

    obj.layer.speed = 0.0;

    obj.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}


-(void) resume
{

CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [obj.layer timeOffset];

    obj.layer.speed = 1.0;

    obj.layer.timeOffset = 0.0;

    obj.layer.beginTime = 0.0;

    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [obj.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;

    obj.layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try animation completion block like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^(void)
 {
     self.label.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200); 

 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^(void)
      {
          self.label.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100); 

      }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

      }];

 }];
```

Comment: for labels this does not work as the final animation just snaps the label into original frame and does not animate into it :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should use keyframe animation for that. Here is a piece of code to do rotation with reversing:

> ```
> self.animations = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
>                    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                     [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"],
>                     [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"]                         
>
>                     , nil ]
>                                               forKeys:
>                    [NSArray arrayWithObjects: THERE_ANIM_KEY, BACK_AGAIN_ANIM_KEY , nil ]];
> CAKeyframeAnimation *kfAnim = [animations objectForKey: THERE_ANIM_KEY];
> kfAnim.duration = 2;
> kfAnim.repeatCount = 1;
> kfAnim.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
>                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0 * M_PI],
>                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0 * M_PI],
>                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0 * M_PI],
>                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0 * M_PI], //here is delay
>                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0 * M_PI],
>                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0 * M_PI],
>                  nil];
>  kfAnim.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
>  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0 ],
>  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.3 ],     
>  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.5 ],  //time of delaying in proportion of general animation duration   
>  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.5 ],
>  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.8 ],
>  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0 ], nil];
> ```

Also you can use remember initial state and animate back in

> - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag

animation delegate method with using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:. This is much simplier and easy to set up delay.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're trying to do, but here's what I'm using to move a view onto the screen, pause for 1 second, and then move view off the screen.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.view.frame = viewFrameOnScreen;
    self.view.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1 options:0 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = viewFrameOffScreen;
        self.view.alpha = 0.0f;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

RIAZ answer in Swift 3:

```
func pauseAnimation() {
    let pausedTime = obj.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    obj.layer.speed = 0.0
    obj.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}

func resumeAnimation() {
    let pausedTime = obj.layer.timeOffset
    obj.layer.speed = 1.0
    obj.layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    obj.layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause = obj.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
    obj.layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```

Comment: how can I use this code ? I have UIView.animation function